# Get Instagram Access token

Tags: c#, social-media, instagram-api

I have my Instagram Client ID, Client Secret, but I do not understand the use of the Redirect URI and why I need it.

Can I get access token without redirect URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No.

In order to authenticate the Instagram user they need to be directed to Instagram. On successful login Instagram will return the user back to your site or another URL of your specification. (this is the redirect Uri)

If you're doing the "Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication" 
You'll get the Access token like this. 
http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

You can now get the access token from the url query string.